# Strange Sidebar formatting

Tags: bug, chat

I was hanging out in [The Nineteeth byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), while also in a number of other rooms ([talk.tryitonline.net](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44255/talk-tryitonline-net), [Primes and Squares](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52149/primes-and-squares) and [Polyglot development](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)).  A user left [the following comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39092376#39092376) in talk.tryitonline.net:

> @Dennis It look like it works, so long as you don't wrap around to the left (translated, mostly not golfed from the non-wrapping variety in the brainfuck Hello World answer): />>>/\/>/\/>/\>>\>[//>>>>[//>>>[//>>>>\/>>/>>>/////>/]///>\‌​/]////>>>]//\\.//\/>>/\/>/.//\.//.//>>>>>>>>.//>\/>>/\[//\/>/\‌​.//////]//

I noticed this immediately because it caused a very strange thing to happen on my side bar

[image: Message out of the room]

None of the formatting present in the sidebar is present when viewed in the proper room:

[image: Message in the room]

Nor do I believe it is intended to be possible to achieve such formatting.  I've never seen any colored messages nor multiline formatting in the sidebar.

The same formatting also occurs when I visit any other room I am in.

I was originally browsing on chrome, where the problem appears but when I switch to safari the problem goes away and the message is displayed normally.

I have been unable to reproduce this behavior either in the sandbox or in the talk.tryitonline.net room.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with Chrome?

Comment: @AnthonyPham As am I.  I think that there is something more important than the contents of the message that is causing the issue.  I'll leave it to the experts though.

Comment: Were you running any userscripts?

Comment: @AnthonyPham I was but when I turned it off the problem persisted.